# Wubi 12.04 installation error executing command command

Tags: 12.04, wubi

I have tried to install wubi but have not had luck because there is an error executing command:

```
>>command=C:\Users\Me\AppData\Local\Temp\pyl4266.tmp\bin\resize2fs.exe-f C:\ubuntu\disks\root.disk 17744M
>>retval=1
>>stderr=
>>stdout=resize2fs1.40.6 (09-Feb-2008)
Usage:
/cygdrive/c/Users/Eriks/AppData/Local/Temp/pyl4266.tmp/bin/resize2fs.exe-f C:/ubuntu/disks.root.disk17744M [-d debug_flags][-f][-F][-p] device[new_size]
```

I do not understand what is the problem. Here is my log file.
https://skydrive.live.com/redir?resid=B4F19CA027FFAD89!324

Please let me know what can be done to fix this error.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using also having cygwin installed in your windows System ? If yes, then first uninstall it, then try again. In my opinion your cygwin installation is interfering with Wubi .

```
Usage: /**cygdrive**/c/Users/Eriks/AppData/Local/Temp/pyl4F88.tmp/bin/resize2fs.exe -f C:/ubuntu/disks/root.disk 17744M [-d debug_flags] [-f] [-F] [-p] device [new_size]
```

Hope this helps...

Answer (score 0):

I have the solution for you. Your problem is, that wubi needs to access the Boot Configuration Data which is located on the hidden SYSTEM partition that Windows 7 and Vista create. But wubi cannot access the BCD because this partition is hidden. I had the same problem, but here is the solution.

1. Download Partition Wizard 7 http://www.partitionwizard.com/download.html
2. Assign the hidden partition a letter
3. Run wubi
4. Be happy

I hope this helped.

p.s This was wrote from Ubuntu